# Find json with specific content using regular expression

Tags: regex, match, matching

I have the following txt file which contains json objects.

```
[2018-12-10 06:30:38]..再同步健康数据... 
[2018-12-10 06:30:44]JSON回调处理--->>> 同步运动数据 [2018-12-10 06:30:44]同步运动健康数据json:{  "day" : 10,  "items" : [  {  "activeTime" : 5,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  },
{  "activeTime" : 0,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  },  {  "activeTime" : 0,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  }  ],  "month" : 12,  "startTime" : 0,
"timeSpace" : 15,  "totalActiveTime" : 81,  "totalCalory" : 0,  "totalDistance" : 0,  "StepCount" : 0,  "year" : 2018 }  
[2018-12-10 06:30:44]同步运动健康数据items.sise()=96 
[2018-12-10 06:30:38]..再同步健康数据... 
[2018-12-10 06:30:44]JSON回调处理--->>> 同步运动数据 [2018-12-10 06:30:44]同步运动健康数据json:{  "day" : 10,  "items" : [  {  "activeTime" : 5,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  },
{  "activeTime" : 0,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  },  {  "activeTime" : 0,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  }  ],  "month" : 12,  "startTime" : 0,  "timeSpace" : 15,  "totalActiveTime" : 81,  "totalCalory" : 0,  "totalDistance" : 0,  "totalCount" : 0,  "year" : 2018 }  
[2018-12-10 06:30:44]同步运动健康数据items.sise()=96
```

So far I have defined the following expression which extract the json objects.

```
json:.+?(?=\[2)
```

I want to extract just one json object which contains element named `totalCount. What should I add to my actual expression?

Posted txt file with replaced places of json objects

```
[2018-12-10 06:30:44]JSON回调处理--->>> 同步运动数据 [2018-12-10 06:30:44]同步运动健康数据json:{  "day" : 10,  "items" : [  {  "activeTime" : 5,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  },
{  "activeTime" : 0,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  },  {  "activeTime" : 0,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  }  ],  "month" : 12,  "startTime" : 0,  "timeSpace" : 15,  "totalActiveTime" : 81,  "totalCalory" : 0,  "totalDistance" : 0,  "totalCount" : 0,  "year" : 2018 }  
[2018-12-10 06:30:44]同步运动健康数据items.sise()=96
[2018-12-10 06:30:38]..再同步健康数据... 
[2018-12-10 06:30:44]JSON回调处理--->>> 同步运动数据 [2018-12-10 06:30:44]同步运动健康数据json:{  "day" : 10,  "items" : [  {  "activeTime" : 5,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  },
{  "activeTime" : 0,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  },  {  "activeTime" : 0,  "calory" : 0,  "distance" : 0,  "stepCount" : 0  }  ],  "month" : 12,  "startTime" : 0,
"timeSpace" : 15,  "totalActiveTime" : 81,  "totalCalory" : 0,  "totalDistance" : 0,  "StepCount" : 0,  "year" : 2018 }  
[2018-12-10 06:30:44]同步运动健康数据items.sise()=96 
[2018-12-10 06:30:38]..再同步健康数据...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex from,

```
json:.+?(?=\[2)
```

to,

```
(?s)json:(?!.*json:.*totalCount.*).*?totalCount.*?(?=\[2)
```

to achieve your json only matching the one that contains `totalCount` inside it.

This negative lookahead `(?!.*json:)` ensures that previous `json:` match is abandoned the moment it sees a another `json:` in the string, due to which it starts doing a match with the closest `json:` instead of the first one.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4XdPvG/2)**

Comment: And if I change the the places of these json objects then this regex wouldn't work. Is there any universal solution.

Comment: @maciejka: I am not sure what you meant by "change the places of these json objects". Can you give me a sample of such text, may be edit and add in your post. I will try my best to give you a universal solution if at all possible.

Comment: I have posted example. This is the same files with replaces the positions of json objects.

Comment: @maciejka: I have updated my regex and the demo link. Can you check if this is what you wanted? In case you still have any thing unresolved, please let me know.

Comment: This answer is perfectly for me. Thank you.